# MvcSiteMapProvider and url with hyphens

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcsitemapprovider

I've a MVC site that is using URL with hyphens (for SEO optimization), example:

```
www.domain.com/about-us/know-our-services
```

Now I've implemented the `MvcSiteMapProvider` to generate dynamic breadcrumbs, but for the URL with hyphens it doesn't work (doesn't find it on the sitemap).

How can I resolve this?

Comment: 1st - seem -> doesn't seam, 2nd - *what* is the problem? we need more details in order to help you.

Comment: How do you generate the dynamic breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to generate custom URLs is to adjust your routes to build your URL scheme. In order for MvcSiteMapProvider to generate the correct URLs, you must ensure your outgoing routes can be resolved.

Routes are a 2-way mapping. The incoming routes are determined in the `GetRouteData` method of the RouteBase class. The outgoing routes are determined by the `GetVirtualPath` method of the RouteBase class. The incomming route is what MVC uses to determine what URL matches a given controller and action. The `GetVirtualPath` method that both MVC and MvcSiteMapProvider uses to resolve the URL with, so it must be implemented in order for MvcSiteMapProvider to function with custom URLs.

Have a look at [Custom Routes in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=970) for some ideas about how these methods can be implemented by subclassing RouteBase. These same ideas apply when registering the Route class - you must ensure 2-way resolving for it to work.